# How to display UiDatePicker to labels in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uidatepicker

My project is a reminder list and has only two view controllers(vc).

The first displays the tableview using **Subtile** style on the tableview cell. The second vc has two text labels, the date picker and save button.

**My questions;**

**1)** How do I send the time only to the label I have created in the tableview cell?
**2)** When adding the date picker to **xcdatamodeld** (core data), under **Attribute** what is the **Type**? I have tried **Double**, but that didn't work.

Greatly appreciate your support.

```
import UIKit

class AddEventViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var addReminderTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addInformationTextField: UITextField!

    var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(datePicker)

    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

    }

    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let task = Task(context: context)
        task.title = addReminderTextField.text!
        task.subtitle = addInformationTextField.text!



        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

    navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
}
```

And here is my tableview code...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) 

        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = task.title!
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = task.subtitle

        return cell
    }

    func getTasks() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(task)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
            }
            catch {
                print("Fetching Failed")

            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the reminder?

Comment: Yes @Phyber, I will add that function. My issue is as above.

Comment: What do you mean by your first question? It seems to me like editing

Comment: UIDatepicker has the time on it. I want to send that time to the label I have set in the tableview cell. To store this data, I also need to create a datamodel in xcdatamodeld. I thought I explained myself well, but I guess I didn't.

Comment: @Phyber Grrrr, my rep isn't hight enough. I can see your message but cannot reply.